# Codeception Acceptance suite configuration error in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, phpunit, codeception

I am trying to setting up Codeception with Yii2 Basic framework. Unit Test's are working fine. Acceptance is also working, but if I want to use `WebDriver` module, I get error. This is the `acceptance.suite.yml` file

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - AcceptanceHelper
      - WebDriver:
         url: 'http://mylocalsite'
         browser: phantomjs
```

Phantomjs is installed and running on `PORT 4444`.

The error I get is:

```
[yii\base\ErrorException]
Illegal offset type in isset or empty
```

This is the composer file to give you idea about versions.

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "protected/vendor"
    },

  "require": {
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",

    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "4.*",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib" : "2.8.8",
    "codeception/codeception": "2.0.16",
    "codeception/specify": "*",
    "codeception/verify": "*",
    "yii2tech/sitemap": "*",
    "geoip2/geoip2":"~2.0",
    "facebook/facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php": "^1.5"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-composer": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
  },
}
```

Is there any wrong with the configuration file or anyone face the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is just an assumption and is not verified. YAML configuration in old Codeception version was slightly different, AFAIK there was an additional `config` section. Your composer.json shows that you manually locked to `"codeception/codeception": "2.0.16"`.

What you could try:

### Update to 2.2

- using `"codeception/codeception": "^2.2"` in composer.json

### Provide additional `config` section

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver
  config:
    WebDriver:
      url: http://mylocalsite
      browser: phantomjs
      port: 4444
```

Comment: It Worked. Thanks @OliverHader